# SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle stdout: Nothing written for capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

When I am doing `cap production deploy` then I am receiving following error:

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
gem 'rvm1-capistrano3', require: false
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
```

Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'rvm1/capistrano3'

# Includes default deployment tasks

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails/tree/master/assets
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails/tree/master/migrations
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
# require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
# require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

deploy.rb

```
require 'capistrano/bundler'
set :application, 'firm'
set :scm, :git
set :stage, :production
set :branch, "master"
set :repo_url, url
set :deploy_to, "/path/"
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system', 'public/pdfs')
# specify how many releases Capistrano should store on server's harddrive
set :keep_releases, 5
set :bundle_without, [:development]
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app'
# set :scm, :git

# set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :trace
#set :rvm_type, :system
# set :pty, true

# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }
# set :keep_releases, 5
set :rvm1_ruby_version, "2.2.1"
set :rvm_ruby_string,           :local
#SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "~/.rvm/bin/#{fetch(:application)}_bundle exec rake"
set :bundle_flags, '--deployment --quiet'
set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('Gemfile') }
set :bundle_dir, -> { shared_path.join('bundle') }
set :bundle_without, %w{test development}.join(' ')
set :bundle_binstubs, -> { shared_path.join('bin') }
namespace :deploy do

  desc "Symlink shared config files"
  task :symlink_config_files do
    sh "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end

end
```

Comment: In general, this error simply means that one of the commands that capistrano executes on the remote server, [failed with non-zero exit code](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/37). Please run the `cap` command with `--trace` and provide the log output if you want more help.

Answer (score -2):

How much RAM do you have ?

I've just solved this issue myself, and it was indeed a RAM issue.

You can try:

1. Reboot the server, try deploy again.
2. Increase the SWAP on your server.

Comment: I am trying to deploy on my local machine

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? You are deploying to the same machine you are calling `cap production deploy` from ?

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain ? This is the exact same error message you'll get when you're out of RAM on platforms like DigitalOcean.